# CSS - hidden div at bottom of the page but visible header

Tags: css

So I have a div that i want to position at the bottom of my page, with the body of the div completely hidden below the user's viewport, except the entirety of a header which is fixed to the bottom of the page.

Contraints:

1. The height of the entire div is dynamic, as there can be any number of items in there
2. The header of the div is contained entirely within the div, syntax-wise

Ideally I'd like to do this completely with CSS, but if a little bit of JavaScript is needed, that's fine too.

Any ideas on how this can be done? `position: fixed` and `bottom: (height of header - height of div)` doesn't work because the height of the div changes when you resize the viewport.

[image: the thing i want to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's my solution. The key is to have a wrapper that is the same height as the header that you want sticking out, and apply position fixed and bottom 0 to that parent wrapper.

html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-top">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-bottom">
    This can be variable height
  <div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-top {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: And for those that want to see it in action, view this at a mobile resolution

https://store.makewonder.com/